# How to prove two tables are logically equivalent if they have different numbers of variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I used boolean algebra to simplify an expression with $3$ variables. After simplifying, it reduces to $2$ variables. The first truth table has $8$ rows and the second one has $4$. How to prove that they're logically equivalent?

Considering $+$ as or, . as and $\sim$ as not.

The original expression is:

$$F = \sim x (xy + \sim(x + y) + z) + z\sim x + \sim(zx)$$

Reduced to:

$$(\sim x) + (\sim z)$$

Comment: The second "has four rows" because the statement does not include 'y'.  So how does the truth or falsity of 'y' affect the value of $F$?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a separate truth-table for each statement, you create a single table for both statements. This is what is called a *joint* truth-table, that has as its reference columns all variables that occur in either of the statements you are interested in, and in which you work out the truth-values of all those statements.

\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
x&y&z&x'(xy+(x+y)'+z)+zx'+(zx)'&x'+z'\\
\hline
0&0&0&bla&bla\\
0&0&1&bla&bla\\
...&&&...&...
\end{array}